# Trouble building a BizTalk orchestration with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, biztalk

I've got a BizTalk 2010 project I am trying to build via Cruise Control .NET. The weird thing is that it's having trouble with the CompileODX target, within the XLangTask. I can compile via MSBuild.exe on the command line, and when my account runs Cruise Control. However, when Cruise Control is running as a designated service account, it fails. The service account has Full Control on a parent of the directory containing the references (I only have Read/Execute). The service account is a local Admin on the box running Cruise Control service and has been rebooted.

I added some logging within the target to output the parameters to the XLangTask task along with the errors.

```
 [exec] CompileODX:
 [exec]   XLangItems = CarrierSolicitProcess.odx
 [exec]   ProjectReferences = C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.External.Maps\bin\Release\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.External.Maps.dll;C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.External.Schemas\bin\Release\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.External.Schemas.dll;C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps\bin\Release\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Maps.dll;C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Schemas\bin\Release\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Internal.Schemas.dll;\\hq.echogl.net\files\Development\Release\Assemblies\Echo.Enterprise.BizTalk.FederatedEventingPortTypes\Implementations\Trunk\Echo.Enterprise.BizTalk.FederatedEventingPortTypes.dll;\\hq.echogl.net\files\Development\Release\Assemblies\Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging\Implementations\Trunk\Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging.dll;\\hq.echogl.net\files\Development\Release\Assemblies\Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging.EventSchemas\Implementations\HEAD\Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging.EventSchemas.dll;\\hq.echogl.net\files\Development\Release\Assemblies\Echo.Enterprise.Framework\Implementations\Trunk\Echo.Enterprise.Framework.dll;\\hq.echogl.net\files\Development\Release\Assemblies\Echo.USS.BizTalkEdiSchemas.CorrelationProperties\Implementations\HEAD\Echo.USS.BizTalkEdiSchemas.CorrelationProperties.dll;C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines\3.0.1.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.dll;C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas\3.0.1.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.BizTalk.TestTools.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Configuration.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Microsoft.XLANGs.RuntimeTypes.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.Agent.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Microsoft.BizTalk.Messaging.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Microsoft.XLANGs.Engine.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft BizTalk\Microsoft.RuleEngine.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.ProcessInterface.dll;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Web.Services.dll;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft BizTalk\Microsoft.BizTalk.TOM.dll
 [exec]   WarningLevel = 4
 [exec]   BpelCompliance = True
 [exec]   DefineConstants = TRACE
 [exec]   TreatWarningsAsErrors = false
 [exec]   TempAssembly = obj\Release\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.ClrTypes.dll
 [exec]   OutputDirectory = obj\Release\BizTalk\XLang\
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(917,48): error X2186: identifier 'EnterpriseEventSchema' does not exist in 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging'; are you missing an assembly reference? [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(917,48): error X2007: cannot find symbol 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging.EnterpriseEventSchema' [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(917,13): error X2153: a porttype operation can only contain messagetypes or class types [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(924,48): error X2186: identifier 'EnterpriseEventSchema' does not exist in 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging'; are you missing an assembly reference? [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(924,48): error X2007: cannot find symbol 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging.EnterpriseEventSchema' [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(924,13): error X2153: a porttype operation can only contain messagetypes or class types [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(931,48): error X2186: identifier 'EnterpriseEventSchema' does not exist in 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging'; are you missing an assembly reference? [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(931,48): error X2007: cannot find symbol 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging.EnterpriseEventSchema' [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(931,13): error X2153: a porttype operation can only contain messagetypes or class types [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(938,48): error X2186: identifier 'EnterpriseEventSchema' does not exist in 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging'; are you missing an assembly reference? [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(938,48): error X2007: cannot find symbol 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging.EnterpriseEventSchema' [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(938,13): error X2153: a porttype operation can only contain messagetypes or class types [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(992,44): error X2186: identifier 'EventProperties' does not exist in 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging'; are you missing an assembly reference? [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(992,44): error X2007: cannot find symbol 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging.EventProperties.carrierId' [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(992,9): error X2166: a correlationtype can only contain message property references [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(992,106): error X2186: identifier 'EventProperties' does not exist in 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging'; are you missing an assembly reference? [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(992,106): error X2007: cannot find symbol 'Echo.Enterprise.FederatedMessaging.EventProperties.operationContextId' [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(992,71): error X2166: a correlationtype can only contain message property references [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec] C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\CarrierSolicitProcess.odx(992,60): error X2166: a correlationtype can only contain message property references [C:\CCNetBuild\FlexTMS.TLAutoTender.BizTalk\Trunk\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit\Echo.BAS.TLAutoTender.Processes.CarrierSolicit.btproj]
 [exec]       : 'EventProperties.carrierId'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the build process cannot locate your EnterpriseEventSchema, is the dll for this schema present in the GAC on the build server?